# Is there a more pythonic way to loop over multiple similar indices using list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have the following code

```
A = [(X(x), Y(y), Z(z)) for x in range(N) for y in range(N) for z in range(N)]
```

It does what I want - produce a list of tuples representing cartesian coordinates according to my functions X, Y and Z - but it is not very pretty. I tried

```
A = [(X(x), Y(y), Z(z)) for x, y, z in range(N)]
```

but that didn't work. Is there a more elegant and pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from itertools import product
A = [(X(x), Y(y), Z(z)) for x, y, z in product(range(N), repeat=3)]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```
import itertools

res = [X(each[0]), Y(each[1]), Z(each[2]) for each in itertools.combinations(N, 3)]
```

This will give you all the unique combinations. You can find more about it [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) .

Keep coding :)

Answer (score -2):

As x,y and z are having the same value, you could do this:

```
A = [(X(x), Y(x), Z(x)) for x, in range(N)]
```

You can also use a map function:

```
f = lambda x : (X(x), Y(x), Z(x))
map(f, range(N))
```

Good luck

Comment: No, that won't quite work: x, y and z loop over the same values, but any combination of different values within that set must be used.

Comment: @josandres - your `A` will have length `N`, while the OP's `A` has length `3N`.